# Вызов метода из другого класса PYQT5

Tags: python, pyqt5

Я учусь программированию в PYQT5 и не могу понять как вызвать метод из другого класса PYQT5 с параметрами

```
def ABC():
   time.sleep(5)
   res='TEST'
   Main.qwe(Main, res)
   #Main.label1.settext(res) ???


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Mainwindow.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.button1.click.connect(self.asd)
     
     def asd(self):
         thr1 = threading.Thread(target =ABC).start()

     def qwe(self, res):
        self.res = res
        self.label1.settext(res)
```

Comment: если сделать ABC методом класса то GUI приложения зависает и ждет пока завершиться поток

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы вызвать метод из другого класса, нужно создать экземпляр этого класса.

Например у вас есть класс Main

Создаете экземпляр этого класса

```
instance = Main()
```

И уже потом с помощью экземпляра instance обращаетесь к методам класса Main
Например:

```
instance.asd()
```

Или обращение с передачей аргументов, первым всегда передается автоматически сам экземпляр а в скобочках аргументы:

```
res = 'label'
instance.qwe(res)
```